# How do I store the row number (position) for each record of a flat file using a ODI 11 interface

Tags: database, stored-procedures, oracle11g, interface, oracle-data-integrator

I need to store the position of each row from a txt file during the execution of an ODI 11 interface using file technology for reading a flat file from FTP location and storing it into a oracle database. I tried with sequence but the problem is that it only ennumerates each row but not in the original order from txt file. I can not modify the original file in any way prior to reading it from FTP. Any help would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: I can now modify file directly from FTP, so I'm trying tu use OS command as follows:
`OdiOSCommand "-FILE_APPEND=YES"  "-COMMAND= sed = '#VAR_FILE_PATH/#VAR_FILENAME' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/'"`
Step execution is successfull but I see no modifications on the original file.
Also tried
`OdiOSCommand "-FILE_APPEND=YES"  "-COMMAND= nl '#VAR_FILE_PATH/#VAR_FILENAME'"` same thing, no change on original file.

Comment: `sed` does not edit files in place unless you specify the `-i` option

Answer (score 0):

I used next OdiOSCommand:

```
nl -s '|' '#VAR_FILENAME' > N_'#VAR_FILENAME'
```

It added the row number to my pipe-separated file. After that, it was easy to model the interface to store the numbered records.